# What to do when including graphics path causing error?

Tags: graphics

I have the following entries before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
```

I have verified that the path exists with the requisite files. But I get the error

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Figure1.png' not found.
```

for the following entry elsewhere in the .tex file:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure1}
\caption{Aerial view}
\end{figure}
```

Figure1 is of type .png in the path `./images/`

Any suggestions about what I could be missing here?

Comment: Does changing to `{../images/}` (second dot) help?

Comment: the images directory is nested within the directory from where I am invoking pdflatex....so I guess ./images should be the right syntax? please point out if I am wrong

Comment: Try just `images/`. Also, I doubt you need to declare those extensions - try commenting out that line.

Comment: I tried making the changes but that is not helping....get the same error

Comment: @cfr Specifying the extensions can make sense: (a) preferring some extensions over others, e.g. using `.pdf` before trying `.png`. This can also be achieved by package `grfext` more independently from the graphics driver. (b) It might be a tiny bit faster, if only a subset of extensions are searched.

Comment: @Vinod There are operating system/file systems, which are case sensitive. Perhaps the image file name is only misspelled in regard of case.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks. I was mostly trying to just eliminate one possible source of error for testing purposes. But I wasn't thinking about cases where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment and I need mark up.

Let us say the `myfile.tex` and `images` folder are both in the folder `myfolder`.

```
              ____ images (folder) -- figure1.png
             |
myfolder --- |
             |____ myfile.tex
```

Then the following should work.

```
            %% This is myfile.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
 \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figure1}
   \caption{Aerial view}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now if you have this floder structure

```
images (folder) -- figure1.png
myfolder ---  myfile.tex
```

i.e, `images` and `myfolder` folders are sitting together, then you need to use

```
\graphicspath{ {../images/} }
```

Note the two `..`. Hope this clarifies.