# How to reference figures with short path correctly?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to reference figures with short path but every time I compile I get a blank space, the code I used is:

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\graphicspath
    { 
    {Figures/}
    }

\begin{document}
\title{\rmfamily\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Title}}
\author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Lorem Ipsum}}
\date{} % no date

\maketitle
\section*{This is a section}
This is just a \ref{fig:abcd}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure}
\caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{center}
\label{fig:abcd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212546/what-to-do-when-including-graphics-path-causing-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your caption's referencing capability is only within the group that you have. Why is this? Well, in a general setting, `\label` uses the most recent redefinition of `\@currentlabel`, and such re-definitions are local to the group they are made in.

In your example you've placed the `\caption` inside a `center` environment which provides a local group, yet the `\label` is outside that environment. So, `\label` never sees the appropriate `\@currentlabel`.

[Remove the `center` environment and use `\centering` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764), which should clear things up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{This is a section}
This is just a \ref{fig:abcd}.
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum}
  \label{fig:abcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```